# How to Keep Static Prefix in UITextField When Pasting String

Tags: uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a UITextField that handles input of currency. The initial state of the text field has a set value of `$0.00` but changes to just `$` when it becomes the first responder.

[image]

I have successfully disabled the user from deleting the `$` prefix of the text field's text by adding this:

```swift
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == priceTextField {
        if range.length == 1 && count(string) == 0 {
            // Deleting text
            if range.location <= 0 {
                return false
            }
        }

    }
    return true
}
```

However, this only works when the user enters text with keys and then deletes text by pressing the backspace key. If the user copies text, highlights the `$` prefix and then pastes in the text, the `$` prefix gets replaced with the pasted text.

If the user selects the location before the `$` prefix and pastes the text, I move the `$` prefix to the replacement string by handling it with:

```swift
if range.location == 0 && count(string) >= 1 {
    textField.text = "$\(string)"
    return false
}
```

I realize that I need to create some logic for using the `range` of the text in the text field, but I'm not sure about where to start.

I'm not asking for a handout of a code snippet, but rather if someone can point me in the direction of what sort of logic I am needing to implement so that the `$` prefix is not editable and always at the beginning of the text (even when selected and pasted over)?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to,

1.If textfield is empty, use placeholder property of UITextField to indicate what needs to be entered.

2.If the textfield has a value,

```
i) in textFieldDidBeginEditing delegate, remove the $ symbol from the value, i.e. when textfield is active.
ii) in textFieldDidEndEditing delegate, add the $ symbol to the value entered, i.e. when textfield is inactive.
```